# How does one supply user defined min and max functions to a type in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics, scope, max, min

I'm porting my vector and geometric math library from C++ to swift and am having diffculty dealing with type constraints on generics. One particular difficuly is min/max. Consider a very simple generic Vector2 class:

```
public protocol Vectorable : Numeric & Initializable {}

extension Float : Vectorable {}
extension Double : Vectorable {}
extension Int32 : Vectorable {}

struct Vector2<T : Vectorable> : CustomStringConvertible, Equatable {

   var x : T
   var y : T

    ....
}
```

And here are my (user-defined globally scoped) min/max functions, defined component-wise, which call the standard library min/max on the component values:

```
func min <T : Comparable> (lhs : Vector2<T>, rhs : Vector2<T>) -> Vector2<T> {
   return Vector2<T>(min(lhs.x, rhs.x), min(lhs.y, rhs.y))
}

func max <T : Comparable> (lhs : Vector2<T>, rhs : Vector2<T>) -> Vector2<T> {
   return Vector2<T>(max(lhs.x, rhs.x), max(lhs.y, rhs.y))
}
```

However, this is not working. When I try to use these min and max functions on values of type Vector2, the compiler issues the following grievance:

> src/math/Vector2.swift:167:19: error: argument type 'Vector2f' (aka
>   'Vector2') does not conform to expected type 'Comparable'
>   let d = min(a, b)

I don't understand why Vector would need to conform to Comparable here. No where do I call the global min/max operator on a Vector object, it is only applied to the components, which are type T : Comparable, and are actually just Float.

It seems like the compiler is ignoring my min/max definitions and trying to apply the std library version.

Comment: How are a and b defined? Where does “Vector2f” come from? –  A *self-contained* example demonstrating the problem is always helpful.

Comment: This question is pretty much meaningless until you supply code that actually compiles up to the point where it actually gives the error you complain about. Without a Vector2 initializer, a definition of Initializable, etc., this is just hand-waving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the lack of necessary information, I was able to reproduce the issue by making some omissions and allowances, like this:

```
public protocol Vectorable : Numeric {}

extension Float : Vectorable {}
extension Double : Vectorable {}
extension Int32 : Vectorable {}

struct Vector2<T : Vectorable> :  Equatable {
    var x : T
    var y : T
}

func min <T : Comparable> (lhs : Vector2<T>, rhs : Vector2<T>) -> Vector2<T> {
    return Vector2<T>(x:min(lhs.x, rhs.x), y:min(lhs.y, rhs.y))
}

func max <T : Comparable> (lhs : Vector2<T>, rhs : Vector2<T>) -> Vector2<T> {
    return Vector2<T>(x:max(lhs.x, rhs.x), y:max(lhs.y, rhs.y))
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let v1 = Vector2(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        let v2 = Vector2(x: 2.0, y: 2.0)
        let v3 = min(v1,v2) // error
    }
}
```

That gives us the reported error message:

[image]

Well, in that case, the problem is merely the omitted underlines in your function declarations:

```
func min <T : Comparable> (_ lhs : Vector2<T>, _ rhs : Vector2<T>) -> Vector2<T> {
```

and

```
func max <T : Comparable> (_ lhs : Vector2<T>, _ rhs : Vector2<T>) -> Vector2<T> {
```

Comment: So this was simply a problem of the signature for my min/max functions not matching my call site, which instead matches the global stdlibrary min/max.  Awesome.